# Can we use custom setting to restrict access for a user?

Tags: salesforce1-app, profile, customsetting, permission-sets, configuration

Can we use hierarchical custom setting to restrict a particular user from deleting object record. The profile has Delete permission on profile for that object. And it should not be changed as per the business. So is there a way to restrict the access for only one user?

Comment: I would recommend using [custom permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5) for that, have you checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have a hierarchy custom setting created `StopDelete`
Create a new field as : 'ObjectNames', have all objects for which you need to disable delete in a `,` comma separated value.

For eg: `ARecord__c,Account` and User as a lookup of any user.

Then in you trigger, from `before delete` context just add a check:

```
trigger ARecordTrigger on ARecord__c (before delete) {

    String currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    StopDelete__c stopDeleteTrigger = StopDelete__c.getValues(currentUserId);
    if (stopDeleteTrigger != null && String.isNotBlank(stopDeleteTrigger.ObjectNames__c) &&
        stopDeleteTrigger.ObjectNames__c.split(',').contains(ARecord__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().name)) {
        List<ARecord__c> aRecords = (List<ARecord__c>) Trigger.new;
        for (ARecord__c aRecord : aRecords) {
            aRecord.addError('Cannot delete record');
        }
    }
}
```